# How to get src file names from ELF file

Tags: elf

How can I get the names of object files(source files will even be better) other than library from a ELF file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get the names of object files(source files will even be better) other than library from a ELF file?

What *kind* of ELF file?

Object file names contained in archive library are visible with `ar tv libfoo.a`.

In a shared library (`libfoo.so`) names of object files are only rarely stored (some compilers *do* store the entire compile command line, and that could include the output object file name).

But source filenames *are* commonly stored in both archive and shared libraries (built with debugging), and are visible with `readelf -Wl libfoo.so`.

If the library was built without debug info, source filenames are not generally available, although you could possibly get some of them with `strings libfoo.so` if the library was built with assertions turned on.